# Firebase FCM: Different Sound Settings for Topic Push Notifications

Tags: node.js, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am writing an iOS app that allows people to set sound settings (either default sound or no sound) for a particular push notification that subscribe to a particular topic.

Different people will have different sound settings, is there a way to send push notification settings to a topic, but with differing sound settings depending on the user.

I have the following implementation:

```
exports.pushNotifications = functions.database.ref('/companies/{companyID}/posts').onWrite((snap, context) => {
    const companyID = context.params.companyID
    const message = {
        "condition": `'allCompanies' in topics || '${companyID}' in topics`,

        "apns": {
            "headers": {
                "apns-priority": "5"
            },
            "payload": {
                "aps": {

                    "alert": {
                        "body": "New gossips"
                    },
                    "sound": "default", //Any ways to vary this?
                    "badge": 1
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
            return console.log('PNForAllCompanies Successful: ', response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return console.log('PNForAllCompanies Error: ', error);
        });
    })
```

I tried to find resources in this area but seems limited. Does anyone have any idea to do so?

EDIT (For clearer description of use case):

In the settings page of the app, users can set the sound settings (either `default`, or `none`) of a push notification when a new post is added with the tag "My Company" like so:
[image]

How I implement this is to do a database trigger to that `company` node. When there is a new post added to that `company` node, it will send a push notification to everyone who has subscribed to that `companyID` as a topic.

However, for everyone who have subscribed to that `companyID` as a topic may like to have sound when this notification is pushed while others may not want silent. With that, is there a way vary the sound parameter depending on the user's preference?

Answer (score 0):

The value for the `sound` parameter should be the name of the sound file included in the app. For more details about the payload parameter, see the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support):

> The sound to play when the device receives the notification.
>
> Sound files can be in the main bundle of the client app or in the Library/Sounds folder of the app's data container. See the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW10) for more information.

"*Different people will have different sound settings, is there a way to send push notification settings to a topic, but with differing sound settings depending on the user.*"

I'm not sure if I understand your use-case properly, but if you want the sound to vary depending on the topic the message it's coming from, you'll have to handle that from the client app side -- determining which topic the message it actually came from.

Comment: Hi, sorry that I might have been clearer. I have described my use case abit more in the edits. Do take a look. If I need to vary on the client side, mind sharing some code how may I implement this?